# How to define a callable mathematical function when using plot in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Suppose I have `f(x)=x^2+x+sin(x)`. Then I want to plot `g(f(x))`, where `g(x)` is polynomial in `x`, then I want to further plot `h(g(f(x)))`, where `h(x)` is another polynomial in `x`, and the it continues. Is there a way to save `f(x)`, `g(x)` and give them a name instead of rewriting it every time?

Currently I just rewrite everything as follows: let `g(x)=2x`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[domain=-1:1] plot (\x^2+\x+sin(\x));
\draw[domain=-1:1] plot (2*(\x^2+\x+sin(\x)));
% I have to rewrite f(x)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like to define a variable `f` that represents the function `f` I can just call and plot. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={
 f(\x)=(\x)^2+\x+sin(\x);
 g(\x)=2*\x;
 h(\x)=(\x)^2;
}]
\draw[red] plot[domain=-1:1]  ( \x, {f(\x)} );
\draw[green] plot[domain=-1:1]  ( \x, {g(f(\x))} );
\draw[blue] plot[domain=-1:1]  ( \x, {h(f(\x))} );
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three curves]

Comment: If you want the trig function in radians, you can use the option `trig format=rad`.

Comment: Do you know how to have multivariate functions? I tried adding another argument to the function, but that didn't work. I tried this: ```f(\x,\y)=\x+\y```

Comment: Exactly that works (with a semicolon). What error do you get?

Comment: Is there any trick to let us write the variable without distracting backslashes?

Comment: @GodMustBeCrazy: You could use PGFPlots, but that is beyond the scope of this answer. (but it will not work with `declare function` - only directly in a `\addplot` or `\newcommand`)

Comment: Thank you. It must be requested as a next TikZ feature. :-)

Comment: @hpekristiansen yes, it works with multivariate functions. I don't know what I did wrong before, but it works.